# Default like configuration menu in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm trying to implement a configuration menu similar to  Android defaut menu (as shown in the image).

Whats the best way? A ListView with some kind of Adapter or directly a Linear or Table Layout within a ScrollView and put the slot manually?

Another question about that: The rows have a very similar structure:

- The entries with the arrow open a dialog when selected
- The entries with checkbox
- The entries with nothing else that opens another activity

Is posible to define those 3 types in layout files and then in the xml (using include or any other option) parametrize the tittle and the description? Or should I change those fields programmatically?

Thanks in advance

[image: Android Configuration Menu]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use PreferenceActivity. It is designed for easy configuration-menu creation.
Example: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/preferenceactivity-basics

Answer (score 1):

You should use the PreferenceActivity. Here is a tutorial about preferences on vogella.de: [Android Development Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#preferences_using)